# Inheritance of list and its first component

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I would like to have a class (this is C++) that inherits from a list of weighted components, and inherits from the type of the list's components, such that I can directly access the first member. I am not sure how this is possible, but basically what I would like to be able to do is have:

```
class Component;

class WeightedComponent: public pair<Component,float>; 

class WeightedList : public list<WeightedComponent> : public Component;
```

Then most of my code centers around building and manipulating this list (NOT the Component itself). What I want to do able to do, is for the following to always be the case

```
WeightedList weightedList;
// ... fill the weightedList with various WeightedComponents ...
(Component*)(&weightedList) == &(weightedList.begin().first)
```

So is there a way I can set up my WeightedList class have its base Component object always **be** (or point to) its base list.begin().first object, without manual intervention throughout the code whenever the list is clear, repopulated, deleted, reordered, etc.?

Comment: A class inherits from a class, but cannot inherit from a list. I think you need to read up on the C++ language first and learn about inheritance and polymorphism. A child class can then access parent functions and data, if they're declared protected or private.

Comment: @Merlin069, actually, of course, you can inherit the class std::list<Type> or std::pair<Type1,Type2> (but this is not a good practice); however I believe this is not what asker wants to do.

Comment: @Merlin069 I do inherit from a list in the same way Equalitiesofpolynomials suggests. I edited my original question slightly to clarify what I need to be able to do.

Comment: Oops sorry, I wasn't thinking of STL when I commented. I guess  I've been spending too much time with Qt containers. Thanks for correcting me - not my finest of moments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in the way you suggest: if you create a new `WeightedList`, this would always be a new, unique object which cannot "be the same" as the (separate) first element of the list. Also consider the case of an empty list, how should the `Component` part of `WeightedList` behave?

One solution, would be, to implement a separate `first_component` function, which returns a reference to the first component, this way you could access it like

```
Component& first = weightedList.first_component();
first.doSomethingWithFirstComponent();
```

What could also be done is to implement `Component` as *interface*, i.e. a collection of pure virtual methods:

```
class Component {
public:
    virtual void method1() = 0;
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};
```

and then design your current Component as concrete subclass

```
class ComponentImpl : public Component {
/// Implement Component's methods
};
```

Then you can also implement `Component` in your `WeightedList` class and implement the methods by delegating them to the first element

```
class WeightedList : public list<Component,float>, public Component {
public:
  void method1() {
    this->front().get<0>().method1();
  }
  // etc.
};
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer, and the alternate suggestions.